# Why do my SQL Server 2016 transaction logs keep growing?

Tags: replication, sql-server-2016, transaction-log

I'm trying transaction replication for the first time on SQL Server 2016

I have the distribution database on `C:\` (I know, but I'm waiting on a new drive), and my bhdb database on `D:\`.

My problem is that within 6 hours, in spite of the fact the log files started as 1Gb in size, it takes both the `C:` and `D:` drives empty space.

How do I stop that from happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you forrest for the great education. Best article, but I'm confused on what to do. What should be my steps?

Comment: Can we assume that before you enabled replication you did not ahve problems with that, or are you just one of the people coming here and not knowing that they have to make transaction log backups? It is not clear from your question and yes, this is like a regular issue.

Comment: No. Idon't know what I'm doing. No, ihave had no issues prior. And yes iclear my logs periodically.  Thanks